# How do I parent-child pairs efficiently?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

Given a table structure like this with Tops, Mids, and Bots exposed in a DbContext:

```
Top { long TopId; IList<Mid> Mids; ... }
Mid { long MidId; long TopId; IList<Bot> Bots; ...}
Bot { long BotId, long MidId; DataTime Timestamp; string Data; ...}
```

How do I write an efficient query to give me the entire Mid table with the first Bot item for each Mid. By "first" I mean the one with the smallest Timestamp. I'm for something like this only better:

```
var results = _db.Mids.Select(m => new {Mid = m, Bot = 
       _db.Bots.Where(b => b.MidId = m.Id)
          .OrderBy(b => b.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()});
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. What do you mean by _better_?

Comment: Well, I have hundreds of mid-level items. I don't want to run hundreds of queries. I just want one query. I was under the impression that I got a new query each time I referenced `_db`.

Comment: Your code gives you just one SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write:

```
var results = _db.Mids.Select(m => new
{
    Mid = m,
    Bot = m.Bots.OrderBy(b => b.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
});
```

You can see the SQL query generated using `results.ToString()`